# Bluetooth LE GUI Tool for Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently developing on a Bluetooth LE embedded project.

For discovering my BLE peripherals, I currently use some apps for Android 4.3 (e.g. Nordic [nRF Toolbox](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/nRFready-Demo-APPS/nRF-Toolbox-for-Android-4.3) and [nRF Master Control Panel](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/nRFready-Demo-APPS/nRF-Master-Control-Panel-for-Android-4.3)) and iOS ([LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-bluetooth-low-energy/id557428110)).

On my desktop PC (running kubuntu 12.04), I currently use hcitool and gatttool from commandline e.g. for viewing and changing the characteristics values of my BLE peripherals.

Did anybody know, if there was a gui tool available for linux, with similar features like the Nordic nRF Android Apps or like LightBlue for iOS?

I want to use the linux GUI tool for:

- explore my advertising BLE peripherals
- connect them
- discover their provided services & characteristics
- view & change the characteristics values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux currently does not have any GUI based BLE tools. The LightBlue referred to in [user1990's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25177672/2880699) is actually an old outdated program that does not implement BLE.

Anything short of command-line BlueZ using gatttool, or hcitool to do what you want, you will not find.

[This site](http://joost.damad.be/2013/08/experiments-with-bluetooth-low-energy.html) has a good tutorial for device, characteristic, and service discovery.

Answer (score 0):

LightBlue is avaiable on linux and mac os X. [LightBlue](http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but maybe it can be helpful to someone anyway.

The company I work for has just released a prerelease version of a [new Bluetooth Smart tool](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/blogs/765/new-bluetooth-smart-tool-from-nordic). It's available for Linux, OSX and Windows. Note that it requires a development kit from Nordic Semiconductor to operate.